# How to process multiple same job but with different input parameters in Spring Batch

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, spring-batch

For my project, we running Spring Batch daily to extract things from DB and send them to others in CSV. I have my job configured, it can be successfully executed for one time execution. But I want to actually do the same job but passing different job parameters into them and run them in parallel. What should I do?

I tried

```
    String[] springConfig  =  {"/applicationContext.xml"};  

    // Creating the application context object  
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig); 
    JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    List<JobParameters> eList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        jobParametersBuilder.addString("instance_id", UUID.randomUUID().toString(), true);
        //jobParametersBuilder.addString("filename", "file" + i);
        eList.add(jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
    }
    eList.parallelStream().forEach(e -> XMLDB(context, e));
```

And then set all the readers to be synchronized by using `scope="step"` in all readers and writers and `SynchronizedItemStreamReader`. Here I used Java parallel stream to process them and XMLDB is a job which inputs XML files into database. It seems working at times, but I think there are better ways to do it right?

Comment: How are you running the job?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine there's a method name `XMLDB` which launches the job and run it. It's very straightforward, no processor sit in between.

Comment: ok I guess you are using the `JobLauncher` API. In this case, your solution might work. Another way is to configure your job and then run multiple instances from the command line with different parameters. This will result in multiple JVMs running different instances of your job in parallel.

Comment: The problem here is that if there are multiple instances' readers running connecting to database, the readers are not closed as expected. It throws error like "the reader is already closed".